# Como puedo resolver este problema usando valores especificos de una lista en una codicion for e if

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for, condiciones, else

Tengo esta llave que tiene varios elementos en ella la función de este Código es que llamar el valor de los números poniendo de los que están ahí o no están es decir que al llamarlos solo me aparezca el número que pido con la función input y no se me cicle además de que al poner otro número que no sea de los que están en la lista me diga que no está en la lista que vuelva a repetir el problema hasta que salga el correcto.

```
questions1=[
["a",1],
["b",2],
["c",3],
["d",4]
]

for sub_lista in questions1:
# elemento sera cada elemento de cada sub_lista.
for elemento in sub_lista:
    #ResP= input(sub_lista)
    #if elemento == Resp:
    if elemento == 1:
        print(elemento,"Es este numero")
    elif elemento == 5:
    #else 
    #print(Este numero no es vuelva a poner el correcto)
       print(elemento,"Este numero si esta")
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacelo asi:

```
questions1=[
["a",1],
["b",2],
["c",3],
["d",4]
]

continuar = True
while continuar:
    entrada =input("dime una letra?")
    # asignamos el primer valor a letra y el segundo a numero
    for letra,numero in questions1:
        # validamos que la entrada sea igual a letra
        # aplicamos el metodo strip para que no molesten los espacios antes o despues
        # descomentar si no quieres que difiera entrea mayuscula o minuscula
        # if entrada.strip().upper() == letra.upper():

        if entrada.strip() == letra:
            print("{0} Es el numero:  {1}".format(letra,numero))
            # cambiamos el valor a False para salir de while
            continuar=False
            # usamos un break para que se salga y no continue al for
            break

    # en caso de no detectar un break en el for se ejecuta esta parte
    else:
        print("{0} no existe ".format(entrada))
```

Comment: Esta muy bien ese codigo y si por casualidad quisiera lo contrario de letras a numeros ¿el codigo de ahi se tendria que modificar mucho o solo una lineas?

Comment: que te parese si eso lo descubre jugando un poco con el codigo a ver que tal...?